# Best way to enhance a Docker image for small changes that need to be persisted

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker image that takes about 45min to build.  As I'm working with it, I'm finding that I sometimes need to add python packages to it for the code I'm working on.  I want to be able to install these packages such that it persists.

What's the best way to achieve this?

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker builds the container image from cache if nothing is changed. When it founds a change in a line, it executes again all the lines from the change. So, if you need to add libraries, just add more lines at the end of the dockerfile.

Comment: I did that for an ENV line, and docker rebuilt my image from scratch...  maybe something gimped, and I should try it again then.

Comment: If you added or changed it at the head of the file, that would ALWAYS redo everything. It would have to be tail-end of the file to not affect anything else. In addition if you have a "copy" or "add" line, and those files changes, it would trigger a more massive rebuild. The one other thing that does it, is if I "rmi" the previous image it clears that cache, forcing the next update to be a full rebuild.

Comment: How are the image caches indexed?  Some kind of hash of the commands?  Would whitespace at the top of the file affect it?

Answer (score 0):

While working on docker I have followed two approaches .

**First** if you have file like

```
1 from nginx 
2 env name:"add"
3 CMD ["nginx"]
```

So if you change on 2 line the first line will we cached automatically .

**Second** Or you can use other approach if your docker file is big you can separate it in two docker file 

On first file you can add all the essential things you want .
 and create images of it

In this way you will not have to wait for 45 min every time for the software download.
and on send file use that image like

from imagename

and to all change staff here